# Direct sum of two rings

Tags: ring-theory

We know that $\mathbb{Z}_{6} = \mathbb{Z}_{2} \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{3}$, by

$0 + 0 = 0$;

$1 + 1 = 1$;

$0 + 2 = 2$;

$1 + 0 = 3$;

$0 + 1 = 4$;

$1 + 2 = 5$.

What I'm thinking is that why $1 + 0 \neq 0 + 1$.

Isn't $(\mathbb{Z}_{6}, +, .)$ commutative?

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}$You are establishing a one-to-one correspondence between $\Z_{6}$ and the set $(\Z_{2}, \Z_{3})$ of *ordered* pairs $(a, b)$, with $a \in \Z_{2}$ and $b \in \Z_{3}$.

This correspondence maps $[a]_{6}$ to $([a]_{2}, [a]_{3})$, where $[a]_{n}$ denotes the class of $a$ modulo $n$.

So you see that 
$$
[3]_{6} \mapsto ([1]_{2}, [0]_{3}),\\ [4]_{6} \mapsto ([0]_{2}, [1]_{3}).
$$

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with the notation, the sum is in fact a way of writing the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_3$ or you can see it also as $\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_3$ in which case it is clear that $(0,1)\neq (1,0)$.